# Symfony 2 get Sonata media file path in Entity class

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle, sonata

When implementing a __clone() method in media entity, I need to get the absolute path of a file to be able to make a copy of the file itself. I've been searching for a long time and I have not found any documentation to get this. Any ideas?

Here it is the __clone() method where I need the file path:

```
// Norwalk\StoreBundle\Entity\ProductHasMedia

public function __clone() {
        if ($this->id) {
            $this->media = clone $this->media;
            $this->media->setProviderReference('clone_'.$this->media->getProviderReference());
            $this->media->setName('clone_'.$this->media->getName());
            $providerMeta = array('filename' => $this->media->getName());
            $this->media->setProviderMetadata($providerMeta);
            // Clone the physical image file too
            $fs = new Filesystem();
            $fs->copy( "original_image_path/".$this->media->getName(), "original_image_path/"."clone_".$this->media->getName());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is possible without giving the Entity class to much responsibilities since you can't tell the absolute path name without having some services ('sonata.media.manager.media', 'sonata.media.provider.image' or 'sonata.media.twig.extension')..

The proper way to go is to build a clone function into an controller. The controller can have all the magic (services and entitymanagers) to do the cloning for you.

See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381179/list-images-in-sonata-admin-bundle) for an example.